# "en" dans "en savoir un peu plus"

Tags: pronoms

> Un peu plus de 24 heures après l'interpellation de l’assaillant..., on **en sait un peu plus** sur les détails de cette opération exceptionnelle.

J'ai vu l'expression *en savoir plus*, mais j'ai pensé que c'est unique à *plus*, tandis qu'ici on a *un peu plus*. Alors, pourquoi utilise-t-on le pronom *en* ? Qu'est-ce qu'il remplace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« En savoir » est suivi d'un adverbe de quantité. « En » fait référence à ce qui a été dit ou ce qui va être dit, ici l'opération exceptionnelle et l'adverbe de quantité indique le degré ou l'évolution de la connaissance de ce qui est évoqué.

Voici quelques exemples d'expressions de ce type :

- N'en savoir rien
- N'en savoir presque rien
- En savoir peu
- En savoir un peu plus
- En savoir plus
- En savoir davantage
- En savoir assez
- En savoir beaucoup
- En savoir long
- En savoir trop

Référence: [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/1)

> **B.−** [L'antécédent représente une prop. antécédente, ou une idée parfois vague tirée du cont.] .
>   …
>   **2. En** = sur cela (qui a été dit ou va l'être).
>   …
>   **c)** [En relation avec un adv. de quantité] *En savoir long, en apprendre davantage.* *Combien de journaux de captivité pourraient en dire autant ?* (Ambrière, Gdes vac., 1946, p. 115). *Elle fit un mouvement pour se lever, comme si elle avait craint d'en entendre davantage* (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 81).
>    - 13. ... les légendes locales **en** savaient long sur les conciliabules qu'avaient abrités ces coupoles mauresques et ces hautes voûtes noires aux suintements de cave... Gracq, *Le Rivage des Syrtes*, 1951, p. 198.

Comment: I asked this question (https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46677/why-does-the-pronoun-en-exist-here-cest-en-savoir-plus-sur-la-vie#) and someone suggested your answer to me. Can you please explain what you mean by "ici l'opération exceptionnelle et l'adverbe de quantité indique le degré ou l'évolution de la connaissance de ce qui est évoqué."? How can they indicate the degree of what we mentioned? And what do you mean exactly by the degree?

Comment: @Manar I used *indique* (singular) not *indiquent* (plural), so the subject is only *l'adverbe de quantité* which is here *plus*. The *opération exceptionnelle* relates to what I wrote before: "what was said or what is going to be said". By *degré* I mean "degree" or "level" (here: "more").