# Why does the pronoun "en" exist here "C'est en savoir plus sur la vie.."

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I know that the pronoun **en** is used to:

• Replace sth that proeeds **de**, for example:

> As-tu de l'argent?
>
> Oui, j'*en* ai un peu.

> J'ai beaucoup de charme.
>
> J'en ai beaucoup.

• Replace the noun after an indefinite adjective:

> J’ai plusieurs anoraks noirs.
>
> J’en ai plusieurs.

• Replace the noun after a number:

> J’achète 5 bouteilles.
>
> J’en achète 5.

• Replace a clause

> Elle est enceinte. J'en suis certain.

> Le football ce n'est plus ce que c'etait, j'en sais quelquechose. (== je sais quelquechose **de cela**/ "en" replaces *le football ce n'est plus ce que c'etait*)

• And recently I've come to know that it replaces nominal groups too:

> Quel sont les îles des Antilles Françaises?
>
> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y en a d'autres? (== d'autres **îles des Antilles Françaises**)

Now, finally, my question: why is **en** used here?

> *Ce que je veux surtout, c'est **en** savoir plus sur la vie de tous les jours des Japonais.*

There was nothing omitted or replaced in this sentence. I thought that it may be the object of "savoir" but "savoir" don't need a preposition after it in the first place.

Comment: I think the answer [to this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26774/en-dans-en-savoir-un-peu-plus)  answers your question. If you do not fully understand it because it's in French just say so in a comment and someone will translate it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, *en* refers to what has been said or is going to be said, but indirectly.

Without the ***en***, the sentence would not be idiomatic. We do not use *savoir* this way:

> *Ce que je veux surtout, **c'est savoir plus sur** la vie de tous les jours des Japonais.* **✗**

While in English, you can say both:

> I want to know **all** about you. **✓**

> I want to know **more** about you. **✓**

In French, only the first sentence works:

> *Je veux savoir **tout** sur toi.* **✓**

and that one doesn't (or at least, doesn't work well):

> *Je veux savoir **plus** sur toi.* **✗**

The issue is that ***plus*** is expected to refer to something (more what?) so we say:

> *Je veux **en** savoir plus sur toi.* **✓**

where the pronoun ***en*** replaces an implicit ***de choses***:

> *Je veux savoir plus **de choses** sur toi.* **✓** (lit. I want to know more things about you)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question that has been indicated in the comments, that is [the answer by user jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26778/17649), does not take into account certain aspects. The reference used in that answer does apply and is repeated here.

> **II.** [Dans des loc. figées ou fam., en a un antécédent implicite]
> **2.** En = sur cela (qui a été dit ou va l'être).
> […]
> **c)** [En relation avec un adv. de quantité] En savoir long, en apprendre davantage.
> ♦  Combien de journaux de captivité pourraient en dire autant? (AMBRIÈRE, Gdes vac., 1946, p. 115).
> ♦  Elle fit un mouvement pour se lever, comme si elle avait craint d'en entendre davantage (BEAUVOIR, Mandarins, 1954, p. 81).
> ♦  ... les légendes locales en savaient long sur les conciliabules qu'avaient abrités ces coupoles mauresques et ces hautes voûtes noires aux suintements de cave... GRACQ, Le Rivage des Syrtes, 1951, p. 198.

- Ce que je veux surtout, c'est en savoir plus sur la vie de tous les jours des Japonais.

For the sake of simplicity, the sentence examined is reduced to the following; there is no difference as far as the syntax that matters.

- Je veux  en savoir plus sur les Japonais.

Notice that the definition in the reference says "En = sur cela (qui a été dit ou va l'être)". What is going to be said? Of course it is the subject "les Japonnais"; this means that "cela" stands for "les Japonais"; therefore, you can say "en = sur les Japonais". It follows that the sentence comprises a redundancy.

- Je veux  sur les Japonais  savoir plus sur les Japonais.

However, this is a redundancy that is not felt because of the obvious difference between "en" and what it stands for; in spite of this never noticed redundancy (nobody will ever tell you what "en" stands for (it's just there)), this is a form that is considered fully correct in French. Nevertheless, this is is not the whole story: if in almost all cases of such less than ideal uses of "en" there is no alternative, that is the only form possible must comprise "en", in this particular case (i.e. according to the definition of the TLFi above) there are a few (apparently an anomaly). This will be one more fact pointing to this redundancy, as we see that the meaning is the same. Besides the 10 cases collected below there are more cases from the 19th century that can be checked on [the same page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il%20savait%20beaucoup%20sur%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). One can see that in all cases "en" can be added without changing anything to the meaning. It must be noticed however that the particular combination of "il", "savait" and "beaucoup" found in the examples is, for some reason, very special: changing any one of the forms (pronoun, tense, adverb (plus, peu, moins) results in not one single instance of the simple form (see for instance [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27en+savais+beaucoup+sur%2Cje+savais+beaucoup+sur&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27en%20savais%20beaucoup%20sur%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cj%27en%20savais%20beaucoup%20sur%3B%2Cc0)).

The following ngram is that which leads to the examples.

[image]

([ref. 1, 1931](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_des_%C3%A9tudes_napol%C3%A9oniennes/-oZIAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) Un mois après, Schulmeister se présenta au général autrichien Mack et lui offrit ses informations sur les troupes françaises, faisant connaître qu'il savait beaucoup sur leur compte.

([ref. 2, 1887](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Souvenirs_sur_Tourgu%C3%A9neff/nTgTAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&pg=PA100&printsec=frontcover)) Il savait beaucoup sur la femme russe , et Tourguéneff charmé l'écoutait avec attention .

([ref. 3, 1847](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Litt%C3%A9ratures_classiques/aqkgAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover))   Il savait beaucoup sur les plantes, les hommes, la forêt et les animaux.

([ref. 4, 1966](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_belge/ttcaAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover))  […] Churchill eut pû dire au monde qu'il savait beaucoup sur le coup d'Etat , et même se vanter peut-être de sa propre participation à l'écroulement de […]

([ref. 5, 1999](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pierre_Chanut_ami_de_Descartes/2JaQZX1f52YC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) Or l'anecdote fut rapportée à Baillet non seulement par le fils de Le Vasseur  mais par Imbert Porlier, neveu de Chanut, ce qui conduit à penser que ce dernier l'en informa et qu'il savait beaucoup sur Descartes.

([ref. 6, 1977](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Contributions_%C3%A0_son_histoire/ya8tAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) Il savait beaucoup sur l ' auteur et sur son ouvrage .

([ref. 7, 2005](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_grande_parcelle_de_ma_vie/t71yAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) Oralement il savait beaucoup sur Baboaté , grâce à son esprit critique , en quête permanente de la recherche de l'exactitude et de la vérité ;

([ref. 8, 1997](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Boches_ici_juifs_l%C3%A0_bas/LqdtAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) quoiqu'il ne le connût pas personnellement il savait beaucoup sur lui et était tout content de me pouvoir dire à quel point […]

([ref. 9, 1925](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_arch%C3%A9ologique/i0bOAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&dq=%22il+savait+beaucoup+sur%22&printsec=frontcover)) Bien que son enseignement ait porté sur des sujets très divers - car il savait beaucoup sur mille choses — c'est principalement comme connaisseur de l'Égypte alexandrine, comme héritier scientifique d'Amedeo Peyron […]